# how to encrypt using hmac within GWT

Tags: gwt, hmac

all.

I was writting a GWT application, at the client side, i need to encrypt the data by hmac and send them to server.

How to encrypte them?
I has google and found the crypto-gwt (http://code.google.com/p/crypto-gwt/), but i was not able to make them work, may since i am such a newbie to GWT.

could someone give me hints on how fulfill this requirement?
or, if the crypto-gwt was working, how to introduce it into our GWT project?

Any comments will be appreciated.

thans a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the jar file to your class path and don't forget to inherit it in your gwt.xml file. put

```
<inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.Crypto"/>
```

for more info click [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/wiki/Usage)

Comment: crypto-gwt looks great, but, I could not find you have implemented HMAC within this suits.